# On google sheet, I'm trying to have a responsive number related with today's date

Tags: sum, google-sheets-formula, formula, responsive

I have a revenue to reach monthly. Ex:100'000 until the end of the month
I would like to have "today's goal to reach" in a cell as information.
It should take into account our actual date (how many days left until the end of the month) And it should take into account how much revenue we reached so far.
Is this possible?

I'm trying to find some information about "how to" online, but since I'm no expert in google sheet yet, I would love to have little help from any of you.

Comment: Now() gives today’s date and tomorrow it will show tomorrow’s date.

Answer (score 0):

see:

```
=(B1-B4)/DAYS(EOMONTH(TODAY(), ), TODAY())
```

[image]

or more precise:

[image]